# Where can I find the 'Mathematics' Stack Exchange site guidelines?

Tags: support, age, math-se

I glanced at a *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange Q&A and saw a reference to the site guidelines, in particular including a reference to a lower age limit.  However, going to help, I could not find any 'site guidelines'.  Can someone point me to the right place?

I have found a 'code of conduct', 'expected behaviour', and several other items in 'Help', but no guidelines and no age limits.

Apologies if I am being blind. Maybe a more prominent link would be helpful!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age for information about the age limit

Comment: As for site guidelines, it's more of a site scope, and covered in the "tour" page, click the question mark in the top bar and you'll see the link. All SE sites follow the guidelines in the Code of Conduct, each site can define different scope though, i.e. what's on topic and what's not on topic for that site.

Comment: No site has a lower age limit. Every user on the network must be at least 13 years old, or, in parts of the world with stricter laws such as GDPR, at least 16.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack Thanks.  Is there a scope document or is it just what is in the  tour page?

Comment: Yes, [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) should give more details.

Comment: Also math has its own meta (math.meta.stackexchange.com)

Comment: The title looks too broad compared to the issue in focus: find the user age rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the bottom of every page, there is a [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service) link (and a [Legal](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service) link, which is just another link to the same page).

Discussion about age limits is in the [Age Eligibility section of the Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age).

In order to ask a question on MathSE, you must have an account. When signing up for an account, in dimmed text at the bottom of the page there is one of those disclaimers that says "by clicking sign up, you agree with the Terms of Service" and other things that no one ever reads. But by clicking, the user indicates that they have accepted.

---

As an aside, I'll note that I believe (but I am not a lawyer, merely an interested observer) that this type of displaying terms of service lies in a legally grey area. On the one hand, if there were a box, popup, or dialog that makes new users indicate that they have read and agree to the Terms of Service then the terms are typically binding --- unless they are so poorly written that they are unenforceable for different reasons. But on the other hand, merely having links on pages are often *not* sufficient. ([Nguyen v Barnes and Noble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nguyen_v._Barnes_%26_Noble,_Inc.)).

I think the MathSE Terms of Service is in the middle, and one would need to argue whether having the dimmed Terms of Service notice sort of near the "Sign Up" button constitutes adequate notice.